# Difference btw Tom/next and Tom/Spot in Fx

Tags: foreign-exchange

I know that for Tom/Spot swap the near leg is settled T + 1 and the far leg of the swap is settled T+2. However, is a Tom/Next same as Tom/Spot swap?

Answer (score 1):

[Tom/Next](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/tomorrownext.asp) is not the same as Tom/Spot and correspondingly they have different prices.  Tom/Next refers to closing out at the end of day and reopening at the start of the next day. So it doesn't cleanly fit into the T+ structure as they generally refer to closing prices.

Comment: Note, also, spot depends on the currency. CAD for instance spot is T+1, but T+2 is generally correct.